# locating null bytes in shellcode

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I have injected my exit syscall shellcode

```
bb 14 00 00 00   
b8 01 00 00 00          
cd 80
```

inspite of having null bytes it works.I don't know why.
On the other hand,when  I try to execute a execve shellcode,in assembly it runs perfectly.But When I try execute shellcode,it gives me segmentation fault.my execve shellcode is given below

```
b0 0b
bb 94 90 04 08          
c7 05 a2 90 04 08 94    
90 04 08 
b9 a2 90 04 08          
ba a6 90 04 08          
cd 80
```

Strongly appreciated if any one help.

Comment: Shellcode without null bytes can be used to keep it as string. Otherwise, there is no any problem with null bytes in a shellcode.

Comment: dude I understand.In my exit syscall shellcode it have null bytes as you can see that.but it works perfectly.I don't know why!!!!

Comment: Can you please post the assembly code you used to get the shell code?